# Play button not working for @videogular/ngx-videogular v5.0.1

Tags: html, angular, dom, css-selectors, videogular2

I upgraded my project's Angular version from 9 to 13 recently. Since videogular2 package is no longer supported with this version, I migrated the application to use @videogular/ngx-videogular and I exactly followed process for migration mentioned on the github page.

After migration, it appears my "Play video" button and controls like full screen, video scroll are missing. This is due to absence of class on the DOM. I compared other environments we have before changes and DOM looks a bit different. It doesn't have "vg-icon-play_arrow" on the DOM at all. This is how it looks -

We are maintaining local videogular.css and I see its already imported in style.scss which is correctly mentioned in Angular.json. I am not an expert in front end and not sure how can I find out why this is class "vg-icon-play_arrow" and flex is missing on "div" element "overlay-play-container"

Any suggestions on how to approach finding whats the problem? or what might be solution?

[Here is how DOM looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPB2K.png)

Note: I already tried using node_modules css which is recommended by @videogular/ngx-videogular by directly using in Angular.json instead of project videogular.css but it gives same results. Also all fonts files are latest as per recommendation

Comment: delete `node_modules` folder in your project and again in command line run command `npm i` and see if it works or not.

Comment: you can also add videogular.css in style.css `@import url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videogular/videogular2/master/fonts/videogular.css")` check this works or not ?

Comment: Is this a css used by new package @videogular/ngx-videogular or still uses videogular2 package? I will try adding it but since Its recommended to use @videogular/ngx-videogular, I am no longer using videogular2 at all which looks to be correct thing to do. Isn't it?

Comment: I tried deleting node_modules in project and running npm install but it didnt help

Comment: I tried adding @import url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videogular/videogular2/master/fonts/videogular.css") but it didnt work